# Symfony Twig - Removing nested collection without displaying form

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

So I have a nested `CollectionType` of `File` entities:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'File', 'required' => false));
    }
```

Now if I display the nested entities like so:

```
<h3>Files</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0;" class="col-files">
        {% for file in form.files %}
            {{ form_row(file) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

With the prototype:

```
{% block _omics_experiment_files_entry_row %}
    <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
        {{ form_row(form.file) }}
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

It generates HTML like so (after JS injection):

```
<li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="omics_experiment_files_0_file">File</label>
       <input type="file" id="omics_experiment_files_0_file" name="omics_experiment[files][0][file]">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove
    </button>
    <br>
</li>
```

And when the delete button is pressed the `<li>` disappears and on save the file is correctly removed from the parent entity.

However, I don't want to display the form row, I'd rather just display the name of the file:

```
<h3>Files</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0;" class="col-files">
        {% for file in form.files %}
            <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
                <p><a href="{{ asset('uploads/omics_experiments/' ~ file.vars.value.path) }}">{{ file.vars.value.name }}</a></p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Which generates HTML like:

```
<li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
        <p><a href="/uploads/omics_experiments/f504b28f1818493d0cbb712e9b3993b009bef857-001 ÔùÅÔùÅ.lrtemplate">001ÔùÅÔùÅ.lrtemplate</a></p>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove </button>
        <br>
 </li>
```

Which removes itself from the DOM fine, but doesn't actually delete the entity.

The `button` element in both cases simply removes the parent `<li>`.

Does anyone know what I need to do so I can have the behaviour of the first example, and the UI of the second?

I've already tried including `{{form_row(file)}}` inside a `hidden`/`visibility:none` `div`, and this caused the DOM to behave unexpectedly so I don't think that works.

Edit:

I've also tried adding a `input:hidden` field with the same `id` and `name` as the form input, and this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a slightly hacky solution, if anyone has anything cleaner I'd love to know:

```
<h3>Files</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:0;" class="col-files">
        {% for file in form.files %}
        <li class="panel panel-body panel-default">
            <p><a href="{{ asset('uploads/omics_experiments/' ~ file.vars.value.path) }}">{{ file.vars.value.name }}</a></p>
            {{ form_widget(file.file , { 'attr': {'style': 'display: none;'} }) }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

While `display: none` doesn't work for the entire `form_row`, it does work for the individual `form_widget` and this is enough for Symfony to delete the file.